# Firewalld Allow 1 ip address from a subnet and drop the rest

Tags: linux, ip-address, firewalld

I am using firewalld to control access to my AlmaLinux 8 server. I have several subnets defined as sources in the DROP zone and it seems to work well.

I am wondering if is easily possible to allow access to a specific address within one of these subnets.

Restrictions to all other subnets is done in the system default interface zone.

Or am I completely on the wrong track.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The answer seems to be in here:

https://agix.com.au/firewalld-zone-order-priority-and-how-to-restrict-all-but-one-address/

Basically it says that source zones are processed in alphabetical order. So create a zone e.g. 00-Allow and add your single IP address to it

Use the DROP or Block zone to ban the whole subnet.